Difference in length for buffer from AVAudioPCMBuffer and file read using AVAudioFile
I have an audio file with audio channels: mono, sample rate: 16 kHz, bits per sample: 16, and around 6 seconds. I am trying to read the audio file in Swift using methods from AVFoundation. I have noticed that the file length is 90881, and the buffer frame length is 45440.
let audio = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "00001", withExtension: "wav")
let file = try! AVAudioFile(forReading: audio!)
let format = AVAudioFormat(commonFormat: .pcmFormatInt16, sampleRate: file.fileFormat.sampleRate, channels: 1, interleaved: false)
let buffer = AVAudioPCMBuffer(pcmFormat: format!, frameCapacity: AVAudioFrameCount(file.length))
try! file.read(into: buffer!)

var array = Array(UnsafeBufferPointer(start: buffer?.int16ChannelData![0], count:Int(buffer!.frameLength)))

I have tried using .pcmFormatInt32 and buffer?.int32ChannelData![0] just to see if the length will be different as well, but found out that this time the file length and the buffer frame length are both 90881.
I am pretty new to handling audio data, could someone explain why is that the case?
